# How i can get connected with qc 12 with rest api

Tags: java

Can u please help me to understand with simple piece of java code to get connect wth qc 12 using rest api.

I gone thorough the rest api documentation but am not clear with how to start with.but it will be helpful if people can show me a simple java code for authentication(login,logout or getting defect details) using rest api. Also want to know do i need to include any jars in my build path.

Thanks a lot friends.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get what you're asking, but if you want to connect to a REST API, there are several ways... I usually use HttpURLConnection, here's an example of a **get**:

```
public String getProfile(String URL) throws IOException {

    URL getURL = new URL(url);

    //Establish a https connection with that URL.
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) getURL.openConnection();

    //Select the request method, in this case GET.
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //Add the request headers.
    con.setRequestProperty("header", headerValue);

    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    int responseCode;
    try {
        responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: Connection problem.");
    }

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        //Save the response.
        response.append(inputLine + '\n');
    }
    br.close();

    return response.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply 0gener . i just want to know how i can autenticate on alm 12 via rest api.
for example:if i can have a java code which fetches all the defects in my a particular domain using rest api.

Comment: send me the link to that API